# How to require user authentication / login for form submission? - multi-part form

Tags: django, forms, authentication, multipartform-data, login-required

I would like to require user login for a form in Django 1.6. However, I do not want to require login until after the user tries to submit the form. Essentially I want the behavior of the login_required decorator but in reverse.

I have a model that is tied to a user. I have a `ModelForm` for this model. When the user submits this form, if they are currently authenticated, it will save the object. If they are not authenticated, I want it to take them to a login/register form. When they successfully login/register with this form, I want the model object to be saved and tied to this user.

How do I accomplish this? I can not find any information on multipart forms in Django

What I am currently planning on doing is passing the model data to the login/register view. When the form is validated, the model object will be created and saved.

However this seems messy because I create the object in both the `ModelForm`'s `FormView`, as well as the login view.

Also, given my current approach, what would the best way to pass the data from one form view to the next? The data is just two integers.

Currently I am passing the data between the two view using the session dictionary.

Comment: user request in your view, if the method is post check if the user has  authenticated and accordingly act.
As for passing data between views, session is your solution, unless you have complex data then use a cache or the DB.

Comment: Thanks this is what I am currently doing, and I got it working properly. It just seems ugly that I have to have the model's form in both views.